# PHP adding dynamic content to a XML file via form

Tags: javascript, php, html

> 

```
<Country id="USA" value="USA">
    <cities>
        <city link="">city1</subissue>
        <city link="">city2</subissue>

    </subissues>
</Country>
<Country id="UK" value="uk">
    <cities>
        <city link="">city3</subissue>
        <city link="">city4</subissue>
    </cities>
</Country>
```

I was wondering how I would be able to append, edit and delete information from the XML while it is on the server. I was thinking about using PHP for this. for example I want to add a new city under the USA or add a new country all together and add cities underneath that new country i just added. I was thinking about using a form to add the information. What would be the best approach to add cities to existing countries, add a new country with new cities option or delete a country or delete certain options. Is it possible that someone can also lay down how the form should be conceptually. thank you

Comment: http://php.net/dom and instead of xml, have you considered using an actual database for this? keeping a file from getting trashed by multiple parallel update requests is hard to do.

Comment: don't try to go to the painful route, utilize a form and a database, if you really want an xml for something else, then build it from fetching values from db

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to use a database (such as mysql or SQLITE) and generate the xml file upon request.

Then, in order to add a country or a city, all you would need to do would be a simple insert statement such as:

```
INSERT INTO locations VALUES('$country','$city');
```

And then have a php file with:

```
header("Content-Type:text/xml");
```

and then simply echo the xml data from the database.